# Bar height a same as before, but not Y axis in ios-charts

Tags: ios-charts

I use ios-charts and set dataset dinamically.

I renew chart after adding new data. Actually i add value +1 to one of the bars. After that I see that this bar have the same height as before, but Y axis on chart increased by the value of 1.

How can I set Y Axis to 50, for example, and then after adding 1 to one bar I would see that the bar height is higher than before?

I try to use next code but it has not take any effect:

`setVisibleYRange(50, axis: ChartYAxis.AxisDependency.Right)`

Answer (score 0):

You could use `customAxisMin`/`customAxisMax` to control the ranges of the axis, instead of the automatically calculated ones.